# React useState setter wont update the value inside a context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

So, I'm using the React Context API to manage some global state for my app

```js
const blueprintList = [
  {
    id: new Date().toISOString(),
    name: 'Getting started',
    color: '#c04af6',
    code: '<h1>Hello World!</h1>,
  },
];

export const BlueprintsContext = createContext();

export const BlueprintsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [blueprints, setBlueprints] = useState(blueprintList);
  let [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(blueprints.length);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(blueprints.length);
  }, [blueprints]);

  // just for debugging
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`DEBUG ==> ${selected}`);
  }, [selected]);

  const create = blueprint => {
    blueprint.id = new Date().toISOString();
    setBlueprints(blueprints => [...blueprints, blueprint]);
    setSelected(count);
  };

  const remove = blueprint => {
    if (count === 1) return;
    setBlueprints(blueprints => blueprints.filter(b => b.id !== blueprint.id));
    setSelected(-1);
  };

  const select = blueprint => {
    const index = blueprints.indexOf(blueprint);
    if (index !== -1) {
      setSelected(index);
    }
  };

  const value = {
    blueprints,
    count,
    selected,
    select,
    create,
    remove,
  };

  return (
    <BlueprintsContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </BlueprintsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then I'm using the **remove** function inside the component like this.

```js
const Blueprint = ({ blueprint, isSelected }) => {
  const { select, remove } = useContext(BlueprintsContext);
  return (
    <div
      className={classnames(`${CSS.blueprint}`, {
        [`${CSS.blueprintActive}`]: isSelected,
      })}
      key={blueprint.id}
      onClick={() => select(blueprint)}
    >
      <div
        className={CSS.blueprintDot}
        style={{ backgroundColor: blueprint.color }}
      />
      <span
        className={classnames(`${CSS.blueprintText}`, {
          ['text-gray-300']: isSelected,
          ['text-gray-600']: !isSelected,
        })}
      >
        {blueprint.name}
      </span>
      {isSelected && (
        <IoMdClose className={CSS.close} onClick={() => remove(blueprint)} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The parent component receives a list of items and renders a **Blueprint** component for each item. The problem is that when the IoMdClose icon is pressed the item will be removed from the list but the **selected** value won't update to -1. ‍♂️

Comment: Ciao, give me a clue: if in `BlueprintsProvider` you write another useEffect like `useEffect(() => { console.log(selected) }, [selected])` what do you see when press `IoMdClose`?

Comment: The weird thing is I don't see any console logs. It's like when the `IoMdClose` gets clicked the update on `selected` never executes.

Comment: And another strange thing is that `setBlueprints` will be executed (you said "the item will be removed from the list"). If you want, share github repo so I can check here.

Comment: exactly ‍♂️ (https://gitlab.com/alexalikiotis/bleuprint-next-demo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, I found your problem: in function `select` you already set `selected`:

```
const select = blueprint => {
   const index = blueprints.indexOf(blueprint);
   if (index !== -1) {
     setSelected(index);  // here you set selected
   }
};
```

When you click on `IoMdClose` icon, also `select` will be fired. So the result is that this `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(`DEBUG ==> ${selected}`);
}, [selected]);
```

doesn't log anything.

I tried to remove `setSelected(index);` from `select` function and when I click on `IoMdClose` icon, `selected` will be setted to -1 and useEffect logs `DEBUG ==> -1`.

But now you have another problem: if you remove `setSelected(index);` from `select` and you try to select one blueprint from left treeview, blueprint will be not selected. So I re-added `setSelected(index);` in `select` function. Removed `setSelected(-1);` from `remove` function and now useEffect doesn't log anything!

I think this happens because you are trying to set `selected` to an index that doesn't exists (because you removed blueprint on icon click). To verify this, I modified `setSelected(index);` in `select` function to `setSelected(0);` and infact now if I remove one blueprint, `useEffect` will be triggered and logs `DEBUG ==> 0`.

If the idea behind `setSelected(-1);` is to deselect all the blueprints in treeview, you could do something like:

```
export const BlueprintsProvider = ({ children }) => {
....
const removeSelection = useRef(0);

useEffect(() => {
    if (blueprints.length < removeSelection.current) setSelected(-1); // if I removed a blueprint, then fire setSelected(-1);
    setCount(blueprints.length);
    removeSelection.current = blueprints.length; //removeSelection.current setted as blueprints.length
  }, [blueprints]);
```

And of course remove `setSelected(-1);` from `remove` function.

Comment: wow, this is some awesome debugging capabilities. Thanks a lot!

Comment: :) Glad to help you. Have a nice day!